# How can I retrieve information from one table to order the results of another

Tags: php, mysql

I've never needed to perform complex queries with MySQL before (just basic `SELECT`,`UPDATE`, and `DELETE`s) and so I'm finding this a bit tough. This is about as hard as it will get for the script I'm writing and would appreciate some guidance.

Taking this query:

```
SELECT * FROM submissions ORDER BY program,title ASC
```

This will order the results alphabetically by `program`, then `title`. But what if `program` was an integer that is the `id` of a row's column inside a table named `programs` (which also contains a column `program_title`). So really what I want is to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM submissions ORDER BY (SELECT program_title FROM programs WHERE id=<program id stored in submissions>),title ASC
```

But `program_title` is stored in another table. How would I go about doing this? Normally I would put things aside and study up on the subject, but as I said, it's about as hard as things will get for now and I just need some quick guidance.

**Update**
Just fixed a problem inside the second query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the spirit of your attempt:

```
SELECT * FROM submissions ORDER BY (SELECT program_title 
    FROM programs WHERE id=program),title ASC
```

I just substituted `<program id stored in submissions>` for `program`.

Comment: Thanks! Is there much performance difference between this approach and the others shown here?

Comment: @sooper The joins are probably faster.  But really you'd have to test your database when it matters to be sure.

Comment: This is the only answer with the correct field names and syntax, so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM submissions INNER JOIN program ON submissions.id = programs.id 
ORDER BY program_tittle ASC;
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `programs.id=submissions.id`? Also, could you (1) possibly adjust it so that it is sorted by first, `programs.program_title`, then by `submissions.title`; and (2) allow me to select also the `program_title` from `programs`?

Comment: submissions should have a program_id or programid field.  submissions.id would be a submission_id not a progam_id.

Comment: @ebyrob good catch! yes so it should be `programs.id = submissions.program_id`

Answer (score 1):

you could try this

```
SELECT submissions.* FROM submissions INNER JOIN PROGRAMS ON PROGRAMS.ID = SUBMISSIONS.PROGRAM ORDER BY program_title ASC
```